# Как заставить блок принимать значение ширинв другого блока?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

мне нужно что бы при динамическом изменении ширины div x, менялась ширина div opisanie, и я знаю что без JS это никак нормально не сделать. Так же нужно что бы линии которые подчёркивают строчки карточки (Автор:, Название: и т.д.) были во все ширину div punkt, потому что изображение тоже будет меняться. Так же желательно что бы при переполнении div punkt он увеличивал свою высоту. Пожалуйста помогите! Вот код

```css
#x {
  margin: 0%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  border-radius: .5em;
  height: 191px;
  width: 330px;
  border: 5px solid skyblue;
  grid-gap: -2em;
}

#x>img {
  background: pink;
  grid-row: 1 /span 4;
  width: 92%;
  height: 91%;
  border-right: 5px solid skyblue;
}

.avtor {
  padding-top: 12px;
}

#x p {
  margin-top: -11px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid skyblue;
}

#div-opisanie {
  margin-top: -24px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 330px;
  height: 90px;
  border-left: 5px solid skyblue;
  border-right: 5px solid skyblue;
  border-bottom: 5px solid skyblue;
}

.opisanie {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='x'>
    <img src="https://i.bb.co/pWqyX20/1.png" alt='цветы для элджерона'>
    <div class="punkt">
      <p class="avtor">Автор: Даниель Киз</p>
      <p>Название: <small> Цвиты для Элджернона</small></p>
      <p>Рейтинг: <b>18+</b></p>
      <p>Оценка: 10/10</p>
      <!--Тут звезды как иконки будут под цифрами-->
      <p>Отзыв: <small>Книга просто класс прочитал в захлёб всем совету</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="div-opisanie">
    <p class="opisanie">Описание: <small>блаблабла скукотища не ну реально! Я пытался придумать ТИПО описание но емае я ее не читал ну реально.</small></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Сформулируйте нормально вопрос, с четко поставленной задачей, а не "надо что бы или текст прилипал к правой стороне картинке или да вот так лучше, и вообще". Желательно со всеми знаками препинания и без грамматических ошибок.

Comment: Это точно, вообще не понятно, что делать нужно))

Comment: Простите писал вечером уставший сейчас перепишу. И попытаюсь знаки применения поставить.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи Вот так лучше?

Comment: @rusgeli Простите вечером писал уставший и сонный и кажись переборщил с написанием текста. То как я исправил намного лучше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче примерно так

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#x {
  min-height: 140px;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border: 5px solid #000;
}
#div-opisanie {
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  border: 5px #000;
  border-style: none solid solid solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
#div-opisanie p {
  margin: 0;
}
#x> img {
  background: pink;
}
.punkt {
  border-left: 5px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.punkt p {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
.punkt p:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id='x'>
      <img src="https://i.bb.co/pWqyX20/1.png" alt='цветы для элджерона'>
      <div class="punkt">
        <p class="avtor">Автор: Даниель Киз</p>
        <p>Название: <small> Цвиты для Элджернона</small></p>
        <p>Рейтинг: <b>18+</b></p>
        <p>Оценка: 10/10</p>
        <!--Тут звезды как иконки будут под цифрами-->
        <p>Отзыв: <small>Книга просто класс прочитал в захлёб всем совету</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div-opisanie">
      <p class="opisanie">Описание: <small>блаблабла скукотища не ну реально! Я пытался придумать ТИПО описание но емае я ее не читал ну реально.</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```